# The parameter 'colour' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsuk8.png)

code here
constructor's this.colour vairable does not work

```
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  Color colour= null;
  ReusableCard({@required this.colour});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: colour,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add your code as text instead of an image. This makes it easier for others to find your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should solve your problem:

```
ReusableCard({this.colour}); 
Color? colour;
```

Because Color isnt assigned yet it can be null.
Dart has nullsafety so the question mark implies the value can be null.
See this link for more details: https://sanjibsinha.com/null-safety-in-flutter-dart/

Edit: you could also do it like this:

```
ReusableCard({this.colour}); 
late Color colour;
```

The late keyword to initialize a variable when it is first read, rather than when it's created

Answer (score 1):

The issue is showing warning message because of null-safety.

On class level `Color` is needed to be initialized before read time. In your case you are using **named Constructor** which is default to act as optional parameter.  You can do  make it `required` on constructor.

```dart
  final Color colour;
  const ReuseableCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.colour,
  }) : super(key: key);
```

Or make it nullable, as @EnviroApps mentioned. But for this case I prefer like above as my answer.

TO learn more about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety)